# Stream video using FFMPEG and FFSERVER

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, ffserver

I am using a simple opencv code to read a video file from the system.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("1.mp4")
while True:
  res,frame = cap.imread()
  cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
  cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Now i want to stream this video feed to an HTTP server, so that it can be accessed by multiple users using the given URL.

I came across Flask but it supports only one user at time.

After going through various blogs, i came to know that FFSERVER and FFMPEG might solve the problem.Now i am stuck on how to send a frame to FFSERVER.
I run the following command..
`ffmpeg -i sintel.mp4 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm`

But i didn't send anything to the FFSERVER.

I am using the code from [this blog post](https://www.alkannoide.com/2013/07/04/play-with-ffserver-a-quick-overview/)

Comment: FFmpeg does not support FFserver anymore. They dropped it from v4.0 on wards. Although you can get it from previous versions, I would recommend looking at Gstreamer.

Answer (score 1):

**Flask** normally runs in single-threaded mode and can only handle one request at a time meaning that any parallel requests should wait until they can be handled.

In order to solve this problem, you only need to put `threaded=True` in your script and this will result in your application handling each request on a different thread.

I attach here in the following two sample Python scripts that should do the job:

**main.py**

```
# main.py

from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from camera import VideoCamera

app = Flask("AppName")

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host ="0.0.0.0", port=33, threaded=True)
```

**camera.py**

```
# camera.py

import numpy as np
import cv2
import time 

class VideoCamera(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture("yourVideo.mp4")

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):

        success, image = self.video.read()                 

        # Image readed by OpenCV is RAW
        # we encode it to JPEG in order to use Motion JPEG for VideoStream after

        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
        return jpeg.tobytes()
```

Comment: i can use flask, but the problem is- with multi threading there is an increase CPU usage for every new thread. And if the stream is accessed by ,let's say, 100 users simultaneously, then the application will crash.

Comment: What is the `--frame\r\n` on the line with `yield` please?